# findpeaks function giving too many results

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the peaks of four magnitude spectrums:

[image: These spectrums]

The amplitudes are stored in variable A (one for each plot). When trying to find the peaks and locations using 

`[peak loc] = findpeaks(A)`

I get a matrix with size around 1000 with most of those values being 0!

Comment: Please read this link: [mre]. Then [edit] your question accordingly. It is hard to know what you are doing wrong if we don’t know what you’re doing. Obviously peaks with a value of 0 in your graph makes no sense, `findpeaks` doesn’t behave that way. So it is about your `A`. And you don’t show how you create it.

Comment: Please check possible input arguments such as 'MinPeakHeight' or 'MinPeakDistance'

Answer (score 0):

In the documdntation you will find  a parameter 'NPeaks' forcing a maximum number of peaks returned by the function. As an example findpeaks(x,'Npeaks',1) always returns 0 or 1 peak(s)